# Why is the argument not taking effect?

Tags: powershell

Suppose i have `script1.ps1` that gets a REST response from Vault containing a bunch of keys/values for `Dev, Test, and Prod` environments.

in `script1`, i have a param to pass optional environment.

```
param(
    [String]$environment
)
```

if no environment is passed as arg on command line, its value is set by default to `dev`

making sure that script1 is fetching the values, i tested the following (from my dev server/environment)

```
PS> script1.ps1
```

that returned to me the dev keys/values from vault...good

```
PS> script1.ps1 test
```

that returned to me the TEST keys/values from vault...good, so script works just fine

Now consider `script2.ps1` in which i call `script1.ps1` to change some connections in Dev environment.

this is `script2`:

```
$response = & ".\script1.ps1" | ConvertFrom-Json
$response[1]
```

and running script2...

```
PS> script2.ps1
```

that returned to me the dev keys/values from vault, because remember script1 is by default setting `$environment` to dev if no argument is passed otherwise...good

However, when i try this now:

```
$response = & ".\script1.ps1 test" | ConvertFrom-Json
$response[1]
```

I dont get anything back!

why is that??

Is there something wrong with this? `& ".\script1.ps1 test"`

Comment: `$env` is a RESERVED name. you should never, ever use it for anything other than its intended function - as the environment "drive" for things like `$env:temp`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I should note I used $env here on SO but in the script I have it as $environment. I'll modify my post

Comment: ah! [*grin*] good to know ... nothing else stands out to me, so i will go back to lurking.

Comment: i just looked at ss64 and the `&` "call" operator. it says >>> `Syntax - & "[path] command" [arguments]` <<< note the args are NOT included in quotes around the thing being called.have you tried it the way the docs say to use it? [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey OMG that was it!!!!! LOL you are AWESOME! [grin]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey post an answer and ill upvote and mark it as correct :D you deserve it!

Comment: kool! glad to have helped a bit ... and i will take the credit. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way you have used the call operator [`&`] is not what the docs recommend. [*grin*] they put quotes around the full command, then a space, and THEN the arguments. from the ss64 page on the call operator ...

```
Syntax - & "[path] command" [arguments]
```

without the distinct quotes it will try to interpret the whole quoted string as the command.

so, change this ...

```
& ".\script1.ps1 test"
```

... to this ...

```
& ".\script1.ps1" "test"
```